# How can I get the RDS endpoint for use in Userdata

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to get the RDS endpoint to use in user data with cli but unable to figure it out.
I need to get the RDS endpoint to inject into a php file but when I try the following I get:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

I am building the ec2 and vpc using CLI and need to be able to get RDS endpoint as part of the Userdata.

I tried the following on the EC2 instance itself and I get the above error.

```
aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"
```

Even if I am able to resolve that, I need to be able to get the endpoint to pass as part of the userdata. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unable to locate credentials` error says that the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) does not have any credentials to call the AWS APIs.

You should **assign a role** to the EC2 instance with sufficient permission to call `describe-db-instances` on RDS. See: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Then, your User Data can include something like:

```
#!
RDS=`aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"`
echo >file $RDS
```

Or pass it as a parameter:

```
php $RDS
```

Comment: If I run this "aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address" on the EC2 just to test, I get Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"., Do you think if I input that within user data it should be fine?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Not sure how to add a role to EC2 when I am building the EC2 using CLI. I am building the ec2, vpc, LB, Security groups but not sure how to assign the role to ec2 with CLI.

Comment: `aws ec2 run-instances ... --iam-instance-profile <Role>` See: [IAM Roles for Amazon EC2 - Instance Profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#ec2-instance-profile)

Comment: @ John Rotenstein, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Although I haven't yet figured out the proper syntax for the role I am getting there.

Comment: @ John Rotenstein, Trying to pass the variable but still no luck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50219697/boto3-cli-how-to-pass-the-variable-content-in-userdata-to-php-script

Comment: Follow up question @John Rotenstein: if the RDS instance takes longer to launch and spins up after the EC2 instance spins up, and EC2 user data scripts are run with the above commands and the DB endpoint comes back empty (because RDS instance is still spinning up and not yet available), how is this situation supposed to be handled so you can send the RDS endpoint address back to EC2 once it is available?

Comment: @cre8value If you are deploying via CloudFormation you can use `DependsOn` to tell it to wait until the Amazon RDS database is ready before launching the Amazon EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working with this -

mac=curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/mac

VPC_ID=curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/$mac/vpc-id

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-2 | jq -r --arg VPC_ID "VPC_ID" '.DBInstances[] |select (.DBSubnetGroup.VpcId=="'$VPC_ID'") | .Endpoint.Address'
```