# Boto3 Cli: How to pass the variable content in USERDATA to php script?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to substitute the server name in the user data with the RDS ENDPOINT.

I can get the RDS endpoint but not sure how to substitute that in the php file properly.

Here is how I get the RDS endpoint:

```
            instances = source.describe_db_instances(DBInstanceIdentifier=db_instance)
            rds_host = instances.get('DBInstances')[0].get('Endpoint').get('Address')
```

Another way is also:

```
RDS=aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"
```

Next I need to pass the RDS variable content to the php script shown below:

```
            echo "define('DB_SERVER', $RDS);" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
```

Here is what I have.

```
    UserData="""#!/bin/bash

            RDS=aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"
            echo $RDS > /var/www/html/test.php

            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
            cd /var/www/html
            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/hello.php
            echo "<?php " >/var/www/html/dbinfo.php          

            echo "define('DB_SERVER', $RDS);" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php

            echo "define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "\$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "Successfully connected to the RDS instance; $rds_host" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "?>" >> dbinfo.php
            """
```

Basically, I need to get the content of rds_host and echo it to the line in the php script where $rds_host is shown.

Also tried the following:

```
    UserData="""#!/bin/bash
            yum update –y
            yum install httpd php mysql php-mysql git -y
            service httpd start
            chkconfig httpd on
            groupadd www
            usermod -a -G www ec2-user
            chown -R root:www /var/www
            chmod 2775 /var/www
            find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
            find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +

            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
            cd /var/www/html
            echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/hello.php

            $rds_host='aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address"'
            echo "<?php " >/var/www/html/dbinfo.php          

            echo "define('DB_SERVER', $rds_host);" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php

            echo "define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpass');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "define('DB_DATABASE', 'dbname');" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "\$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "if (mysqli_connect_errno()) echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();">> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "Successfully connected to the RDS instance; $rds_host" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
            echo "?>" >> dbinfo.php
            """
```

)

and checking the cloud-init-output.log shows:

```
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 17: =aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address": command not found
```

Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 finished at Mon, 07 May 2018 23:36:15 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 15.83 seconds

Comment: FYI, User Data runs as `root`, so you do not need to (should not?) use `sudo` in the commands.

Comment: Thanks modified it but still can't get the RDS endpoint in the php file. Even though I am able to pull the RDS end point name. Will update the questions to remove sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update –y
yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
.....

rds_host=$(aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address")

echo "<?php " > /var/www/html/dbinfo.php
echo "define('DB_SERVER', $rds_host);" >> /var/www/html/dbinfo.php

etc.
```

Comment: No, opening the file on EC2 instance, the place where the $rds_host is, is just blank. define('DB_SERVER', );

Comment: I really thought this would work. So far tried many different combinations but still no luck.

Comment: Check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` to see if there were errors running the User Data (such as invalid credentials). You can also run the commands manually to test them... login, change to root with `sudo su -` and then paste in the User Data to see what happens.

Comment: doing it now. didn't know i can run the use data as root. Just copy the entire user date to the command line on EC2 as root? that will save me a ton of time. since now I have to wipe out the entire stack and rerun every time to test

Comment: Here it is: command not found: /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 17: =aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address": command not found

Comment: So, debug it! Make sure you are either wrapping the command in back-ticks or in `$(aws rds...)`.

Comment: If I wrap it in back-ticks as root on ec2, I get "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure". if I wrap it in (), $rds_host=(aws rds --region ca-central-1 describe-db-instances --query "DBInstances[*].Endpoint.Address")
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `aws'. Will try to debug and figure out. Thank you for all your help and pointers.

Comment: Credentials error: This is the same as your other Question. You need to assign a Role to the EC2 instance. It means the command is being correctly executed. I've also updated my sample code because it should be `rds_host=$(aws rds..)` (without the `$` I put in front before).

Comment: You are right, I have been hacking at this all day. Thank you again, will accept and start reading to figure out how to add the role to Ec2 on user data. Thank YOU again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170575/discussion-between-stryker-and-john-rotenstein).